# C++ / Java JNI got exception unsastisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Trying to create a simple JNI program, but always get exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libLearningAccessJNI.sayHello()J when calling the method inside.

Below is snapshot of my java code :

```
public class LearningAccessJava
{   
    static 
    {
        System.load("C:/vob/Debug/libLearningAccessJNI.dll");
    }

    // Declare native method
    private native void sayHello();

    // Test Driver
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        try
        {
            LearningAccessJava testJava = new LearningAccessJava();
            testJava.sayHello();
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            // Always get this exception
        }
    }
}
```

The libLearningAccessJNI.dll is the dll that I created by compiling this cpp and h code below.
This is snapshot of my c++ LearningAccessJNI.cpp and h file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LearningAccessJava.h"

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_LearningAccessJava_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    printf("Hello World TEst\n");
    //cout << "TEST TEST " << endl;
    return;
}
```

And this is my LearningAccessJava.h file that I created using javah.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class LearningAccessJava */

#ifndef _Included_LearningAccessJava
#define _Included_LearningAccessJava
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     LearningAccessJava
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_LearningAccessJava_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us with the gcc command line you used to compile the cpp file? Make sure:

- You use command line options `-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias` and `-shared`.
- The path of the output .dll file is actually `"C:/vob/Debug/libLearningAccessJNI.dll"`

Comment: Hello MNos, Thanks a lot. The command line options is the thing that I'm missing. It works now.